# What is the RDF data model graph structure?

Tags: rdf

Is RDF data model represents data in a directed acyclic graph or not? I am a bit confused about it.

Answer (score 4):

The RDF data model is, technically, a set of triples (each triple consisting of a subject, a predicate, and an object), which can be visualized as a directed, labeled graph. 
It is *directed* because edges correspond to RDF triples, where the source vertex corresponds to the triple's subject, the edge to the predicate, and the target vertex to the object.

It is *labeled* because both vertices and edges have names (IRIs or literal values).

It is *not* acyclic; it is perfectly valid to have two triples in an RDF dataset like so:

```
:a :p :b .
:b :p :a .
```

or indeed this:

```
:a :p :a .
```

It can be considered a hypergraph if you take the notion of *named graphs* (basically a labeling mechanism for subsets of an RDF dataset) into account.

Note that RDF is not actually formally defined in terms of a (mathematical) graph, but has its formal definitions rooted in set theory instead. See the [RDF Semantic](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/)s specification for details.

For more details on the RDF data model, I suggest you read the [RDF Primer](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-primer/#section-data-model) and/or the [Concepts and Abstract Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/) specification.